# XDMP-LEXVAL viewing database status

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am getting the following error viewing the status page of a database:

```
500: Internal Server Error
XDMP-LEXVAL: fs:average("0.1031753") -- Invalid lexical value "0.1031753"
In /MarkLogic/Admin/lib/database-status-form.xqy on line 847
In displayForm()
$dbnode = <database xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">...</database>
$dbid = db:database-id("5028891274155387467")
$dbname = db:database-name("Documents")
$security-db-name = "Security"
$security-db-id = db:database-id("10247912322988672828")
$ear-enabled = "off"
$forests = xs:unsignedLong("10435492011174959372")
$master-forests = xs:unsignedLong("10435492011174959372")
$replica-forests = ()
$replica-word = "replicas"
$fstats = <forest-status xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest"><forest-id>...</forest-id>...</forest-status>
$fcounts = <forest-counts xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest"><forest-id>...</forest-id>...</forest-counts>
$offline-fcounts = ()
$schema-dbid = db:database-id("15863131018639151308")
$schema-forests = xs:unsignedLong("8187375150968556889")
$schema-master-forests = xs:unsignedLong("8187375150968556889")
$schema-replica-forests = ()
$schema-fstats = <forest-status xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest"><forest-id>...</forest-id>...</forest-status>
$schema-fcounts = <forest-counts xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest"><forest-id>...</forest-id>...</forest-counts>
$schema-offline-fcounts = ()
$trigger-dbid = db:database-id("5001115759362581224")
$trigger-forests = xs:unsignedLong("12149639673911694816")
$trigger-master-forests = xs:unsignedLong("12149639673911694816")
$trigger-replica-forests = ()
$trigger-fstats = <forest-status xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest"><forest-id>...</forest-id>...</forest-status>
$trigger-fcounts = <forest-counts xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest"><forest-id>...</forest-id>...</forest-counts>
$trigger-offline-fcounts = ()
$mstate = "available since November&#160;10,&#160;2018&#160;2:09:17&#160;PM"
$schema-mstate = "available since November&#160;10,&#160;2018&#160;2:09:17&#160;PM"
$trigger-mstate = "available since November&#160;10,&#160;2018&#160;2:09:17&#160;PM"
$other = "&amp;section=database&amp;database=5028891274155387467"
$ord = ""
$slch = fs:count("0")
$slcm = fs:count("2")
$slchr = xs:float("0")
In /MarkLogic/Admin/lib/database-status-form.xqy on line 2662
In databaseStatusPage(<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database" xsi:schemaLocation="..." .../>, <databases xsi:schemaLocation="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database..." .../>, ())
$schemaroot = <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database" xsi:schemaLocation="..." .../>
$datanode = <databases xsi:schemaLocation="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database..." .../>
$msgs = ()
In /database-status.xqy on line 16
```

I already tried clearing the database. After that, i do **not** get this error anymore. As soon as i insert a document this error returns. This behavior is the same for all databases.

Is this a known error ?
Using MarkLogic `9.0.7`.

Comment: Is there anything special about the document? Does it work if you insert an xml doc containing only `<test/>`?

Comment: Nope, nothing special. `xdmp:document-insert("test.xml",<test/>)` raises the error.

Comment: Did you upgrade from an older version? I'd recommend reaching out to Support if possible..

Comment: Hm i upgraded from 9.0-4 some time ago. Not sure if it worked directly after that upgrade. Anyway, this is a developer machine, so i reinstalled MarkLogic and it now seems to work again.